# R - How to execute multiple stats functions per group?

Tags: r

I would like to ask for tips on how to execute multiple statistical test(e.g. t-test, f-test, ks-test) for multiple groups. Basically, I want to run the statistical tests as many times as the number of groups available in my data and come up with a single result. In this case, I am trying to do a t-test to compare current and previous year data grouped by a variable(let's say dealer code).

I have a data similar to the below (stress) and would like to find out if there is a generic approach on how to do this? I managed to use rstatix for t-test but it doesn't have this function for f-test and ks-test.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
library(datarium)
library(rstatix)

data("stress", package = "datarium")
set.seed(123)
stress%>% sample_n_by( size = 60)

stat.test <- stress %>%
  group_by(exercise) %>%
  t_test(score~ treatment) %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test
```